# How to open a link from custom swf player which posted on wall

Tags: hyperlink, youtube, flash, soundcloud, facebook-wall

I'm really wondering about how youtube or soundcloud flash player on facebook wall posts can open url on another tab/window. I tried many things from `navigateToURL` (both url and javascript) to `ExternalInterface`, but I couldn't get it work.

Comment: well, no body here hasn't any idea about that? so frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex, this worked for my `onclick`:

```
var urlReq:* = new URLRequest(YourURL);
navigateToURL(urlReq, "_blank");
```

Here's [an example](https://www.facebook.com/MyCloudPlayer/posts/300658353333124) where the bottom link is opened in new window.